# Attach database failed to SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have installed MS Sql Server 2012 in my desktop and trying to write a c# program to

attach DB file to SQL Server 2012 ,while i am executing the program error message thrown

as mention below,can you please help me out to solve

below error message thrown by MS SQL Server 2012,

the DB files(mdf and ldf)

using below code :

Method :

```
AttachDb("sqlDb","[C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\sqlDb.mdf] [C:Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\sqlDb_log.ldf]");
```

Error Message :

```
    80131501 Error: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
    From: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabaseWorker(String name, StringCollection files, String owner, AttachOptions attachOptions)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabase(String name, StringCollection files)
    80131500 Error: Attach database failed for Server 'sqlDbServer'. 
     From: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabase(String name, StringCollection files)
        at TestSMO.AttachDb(String dbname, String filelist)
```

Code:

```
     static string instance = "";
     static string username = "";
     static string password = "";
     static string connection_timeout = "600";
     static string statement_timeout  = "3600";

    //create server connection object 
    static Server Connect()
    {
    ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection();
    instance="sqlDbServer";
    if (instance.Length > 0)
        conn.ServerInstance = instance;

    if (username.Length > 0) {
        conn.LoginSecure = false;
        conn.Login = username;
        conn.Password = password;
    }

    conn.ConnectTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(connection_timeout);
        conn.StatementTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(statement_timeout);
        return new Server(conn);
    }



    //performing attache DB 
     static void AttachDb(string dbname, string filelist)
        {
            string[] files = filelist.Split(new char[] {'['}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            StringCollection dbfiles = new StringCollection();
            foreach (string s in files) {
                string s1 = s.TrimEnd(null);
                s1 = s1.TrimEnd(']');
                if (s1.Length > 0) dbfiles.Add(s1);
            }
            Server svr = Connect();
            string name = DecodeString(dbname);
            svr.AttachDatabase(name, dbfiles);
        }
```

Comment: Is this the full exception including all inner exceptions? SQL Server usually generates better messages.

Comment: Why are you putting square brackets around the file names? They're strings, not identifiers.

Comment: Hi usr, thanks for quick reply,given exception is "full exception" taken from consol

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for quick reply, the square brackets help me to split the mdf and ldf file path. given filepath string arugument value is ""[C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\sqlDb.mdf] [C:Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\sqlDb_log.ldf]")".

Answer (score -1):

Issued solved by providing all server roles to **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** Login of SQL Server DB instance.